# Imitating fortran print and write syntaxes in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ostream

I am trying to implement a class in C++ to imitate the syntax of the print and write statements from FORTRAN.

In order to achieve this, I implemented a class `fooprint` and overloaded `fooprint::operator,` (comma operator). Since this class should print to the standard output or to a file, I also defined two macros: `print` (for stdout) and `write` (to operate on files).

I get compilation errors when trying to use `write(data) a;` (see below for error log). **How can I get a working `write` statement with the above properties?**

This is the code ([Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb6c1d70dfebd9a)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class fooprint
{
    private:
      std::ostream *os;

    public:
      fooprint(std::ostream &out = std::cout) : os(&out) {}
      ~fooprint() { *os << std::endl;}

      template<class T>
      fooprint &operator, (const T output)
      {
        *os << output << ' ';
        return *this;
      }
};

#define print      fooprint(),     // last comma calls `fooprint::operator,`
#define write(out) fooprint(out),

int main()
{
  double a = 2.0;

  print "Hello", "World!";        // OK
  print "value of a =", a;        // OK
  print a;                        // OK

  std::ofstream data("tmp.txt");
  write(data) "writing to tmp";   // compiles with icpc; it doesn't with g++ 
  write(data) a;                  // this won't compile
  data.close();
  return 0;
}
```

And the compilation message:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o print print.cc
   error: conflicting declaration ‘fooprint data’
   #define write(out) fooprint(out),
                                   ^
   note: in expansion of macro ‘write’
     write(data) a;
     ^
   error: ‘data’ has a previous declaration as ‘std::ofstream data’
   error: conflicting declaration ‘fooprint a’
     write(data) a;
                 ^
   error: ‘a’ has a previous declaration as ‘double a’

icpc -Wall -std=c++11 -o print print.cc
   error: "data" has already been declared in the current scope
     write(data) a;
   error: "a" has already been declared in the current scope
     write(data) a;
```

Comment: Put another pair of braces around `out` (i.e `fooprint((out))` or `fooprint{out}`) so that it's a construction of a temporary rather than a variable declaration.

Comment: :o it worked with braces: `fooprint({out})`.  What if I do not use c++11?

Comment: My mistake, `fooprint((out))` should be `(fooprint(out))`. That should work for any version of C++.

Comment: perfect! thank you. Where did you learn this "trick"? :o

Comment: I learned it from a comment I saw a couple years ago. And now you learned it! :)

Comment: jeje excellent. Please feel free to post your suggestion as an answer ;)

Comment: It is generally a very bad idea to use the preprocessor to implement a different language on top of C/C++. It knots brains, and is a quite fertile bug farm due to syntax-agnostic operation of the C-preprocessor. And Fortran is probably not the best language to imitate either. I'd strongly recommend to just use the C or C++ I/O-stream facilities.

Comment: @cmaster assuming this serves as an academic example, what do you suggest instead of using preprocessor directives? and aside that this print syntax is similar in python and IDL, I cannot conceive that "Fortran is probably not the best language to imitate", especially when it is heavily used in scientific research. And, how can I modify the `operator <<` to print a space after any object? (i.e. printing "a b" in `cout << a << b;` without explicitly using ' ' between a and b)

Comment: As I said, what you are trying to do is probably not worth trying. If you want to change the behavior of the existing `operator <<`, your best bet is to wrap the `std::ostream` and define a templated `operator <<` for it that calls through to the standard `operator <<` to do its work. And don't be fooled by the wide use of Fortran in some scientific disciplines. I have seen their code, it's scary at best. These people use an ill suited tool because of inertia (existing code, their masters used it, it's the only tool they know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fooprint(out)` is not the creation of a temporary but rather the declaration of a variable of type `fooprint` with the name provided as the argument to the macro. In order to not make this a declaration, and instead an expression, two quick changes you can make are surrounding it in parenthesis `(fooprint(out))` or using brace-initialization (C++11) (`fooprint{out}`).